# Can non-expanded commands be retrieved?

Tags: bash, command-history

I can fetch earlier commands in the bash history and alter to re-use. E.g. !-5:s/uc1/uc2/, which takes the command 5 lines back and performs the substitution. However, I want to do this five times in a row with different commands. Is there any way to put the non-expanded "!-5:s/uc1/uc2" command into the command history?

Comment: Switch from relative numbers to absolute numbers by removing `-`?

Comment: That is a way as well as pasting from the buffer. I think I was looking for a more generic "repeat but do not expand" shortcut but maybe it's a trivial situation easily solved by other means?